# Unable to send mail using graph API

Tags: c#, .net-core, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c, blazor-webassembly

Unable send mail using Microsoft-Graph-API (Azure AD B2c).

I have tried following code but not working

```
            IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
            .Create(appId)
            .WithTenantId(tenantId)
            .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
            .Build();

            ClientCredentialProvider authProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(confidentialClientApplication);

            GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);

            Message message = new Message
            {
                Subject = "Subject of mail",
                Body = new ItemBody
                {
                    ContentType = BodyType.Text,
                    Content = "Mail content",
                },
                ToRecipients = new List<Recipient> 
                { 
                    new Recipient 
                    {
                        EmailAddress = new EmailAddress
                        {
                            Address = email,
                        }
                    }
                },
            };

            await graphClient.Me.SendMail(message).Request().PostAsync();
```

It gives following error :

```
Code: OrganizationFromTenantGuidNotFound
Message: The tenant for tenant guid 'xxxxxx' does not exist.
Inner error:
    AdditionalData:
    requestId: 0ecdb3f9-a210-4259-bd62-0c79e757d1f6
    date: 2020-08-05T02:17:07
    request-id: 0ecdb3f9-a210-4259-bd62-0c79e757d1f6
ClientRequestId: 0ecdb3f9-a210-4259-bd62-0c79e757d1f6
```

Note : Also Given permission for Mail.Send

Comment: Could you please provide the requestid and timestamp so that I can look into it internally?. And also please check if you were able to get users or facing the same error.

Comment: @Shiva-MSFTIdentity 
I have updated requestId in question, User creation, deletion and get are working, there is no any issue.

Comment: Hi do you have a chance to look into my answer?

Answer (score 0):

This is because your Azure AD B2C tenant doesn't have an Exchange online license under O365 subscription.

So the B2C user doesn't have a mailbox to send the email although its UPN looks like an email address.

Try to assign an O365 subscription to the tenant and add an Exchange online license to the B2C user if possible.